# 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee Axle Part Identification

Tags: jeep, leak, part-identification, axle, differential

I have a 1995 Jeep Grand Cherokee Loredo.  Looking under the driver side rear, I noticed a detached tube dangling. One end of the tube is connected to a saturated/leaking box on the axle and I'm not sure what the detached end is supposed to be attached to.  I can't find this part on any of the diagrams I've looked at.  What is it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a differential vent tube. If so, the dangling end is meant to be up high. This is to allow the axle to breathe at the same time the axle might be under water. Many 4x4 vehicles have this. During regular operation as the diff lube gets warmed up, it expands. The vent tube allows for air to go in and out. Without some kind of breather, pressure would build up and eventually cause the seals to leak. The breather should also keep dirt/debris out of the differential as well.

I'm not sure where at the top it should attach to, but besides attaching it so the loose end isn't hanging down (it just needs to leave enough hose travel so it doesn't get stretched), you need to make sure the end of it is clean. It appears there's an amount of gear oil which has collected on the end of it along with dirt/debris. This has made it so it's not "breathing" any longer and is causing the seepage where it's attached to the differential housing. By cleaning up both ends of the tube and ensuring air can pass through it, it should solve your issues for you.

Comment: @Paulster2 I added a pic of my differential.  I was planning on changing the gasket.  And now I'll also attempt to clean and clear out the vent tube.  Does this sound like a good course of action?

Comment: @user3080392 - Absolutely! It could probably use new gear oil (make sure you get the right weight ... you'll also need to know if you need friction modifiers for a limited slip if so equipped). None of it should be too difficult. It's a stinky job, though, so make sure you have your nitrile gloves when working in the goo.